# How to add buttons to the top bar of a detail view from a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

When an item from a UITableView is selected, a detail view is loaded which has a banner bar at the top with a back button on it to navigate back to the table.

How do I add other buttons to that banner bar?

Answer (score 4):

As Andrew said, you can add custom views to the navigation bar.  For example, if you are looking to add multiple buttons to the right side of the navigation bar, you can do something like this:

```
// right side of nav bar
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 106, 44)];
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

UIBarButtonItem *deleteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(deleteAction:)];
deleteButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:deleteButton];
[deleteButton release];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                           target:nil
                           action:nil];
[buttons addObject:spacer];
[spacer release];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(cancelAction:)];
cancelButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
[buttons addObject:cancelButton];
[cancelButton release];

[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
toolbar.barStyle = -1;
[buttons release];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

Make sure to adjust the width (106 above) if you need more or wider buttons, and then provide methods for the selectors (deleteAction: and cancelAction: above).

Comment: Perfect.  I was nearly there on my own :D  Thanks.

Comment: Dave: If the answer helped you out, could you click the little check below the up/down number to mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it sounds like you have a UINavigationController correctly set up. That "banner bar" you are describing is properly called a navigation bar.

From within the detail view, you can use:

```
UIBarButtonItem* button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:"HiMom" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(onHiMom:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

You can also add custom views (instead of a button) plus a few other settings. I suggest poking around the documentation for UINavigationItem, UINavigationBar, and UIBarButtonItem for ideas.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  Of course what I really want to do is add three separate buttons to the navigation bar.  Seems to do that I'll have to setup something more complex.

Comment: Like a Segmented Control? I saw something like that on here recently. You can create a BarButtonItem with a custom view (eg containing three buttons), or replace the title view with a custom view (via the navigation item's titleView property) and put buttons in there.